# What to do if an exact permutation test is infeasible

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, permutation-test

For permutation tests, it is often infeasible to enumerate all permutations. There are two approaches to solve this. The first uses a random number of permutations instead of all permutation (this is sometimes called approximate, or Monte Carlo). The second uses a parametric distribution to which the permutation distribution should converge to (this is called asymptotic).

I am wondering whether there are any guidelines on which of these approaches to prefer. I guess this is difficult to answer in general. So, let's take the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (WMW) test as an example. For this example, my question is of practical relevance for many applied researchers as SPSS gives you the option to choose between the exact, the approximate, or the asymptotic approach. In case there is enough time to calculate the exact $p$-value, the choice is clear, but what to do if this is not the case? Should you use the approximate or the asymptotic approach?

For the approximate approach, SPSS uses 10000 random permutations per default. This default is also present in equivalent R packages. So, this makes the question even very concrete: What should be preferred (under which condition): The approximate version of the WMW test with 10,000 random permutations or the asymptotic approach?

In my experience, if the sample size is big enough that an exact value cannot be determined anymore, I would expect only minimal differences between the approximate and the asymptotic approach. But I would love to have a better answer to this question.